# open new tab on submitting html form from function called on anchor tag click event in angular-5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms

I have below requirement in angular-5, where i have navigation/anchor tag link and on anchor tag click event i am calling function "gotoApp1()", that function submitting HTML form programmatically to open application/website in new tab with same user session("keyField" in code is treated session here).

HTML code:

```
<div>
...
...
...
...

<div>
  <form id="app1" method="post" stype.display="none" target="_blank">
    <input id="key" name="key" type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="keyField">
    <input id="timeOut" name='timeOut' type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="timeOutField">
  </form>
</div>

<div>
    <nav>
      <a class="item selected" href="#"><img class="icon" src="images/work.svg"><span>Container</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item" href="#" (click)="gotoApp1()"><img class="icon" src="images/app1.svg"><span>App-1</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item" href="#" (click)="gotoApp2()"><img class="icon" src="images/app2.svg"><span>App-2</span></a>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Code behind file i.e. typescript(.ts) file:

```
export class MajorComponent implements OnInit {

private keyField:string;
private timeoutInterval = 2000; // seconds

ngOnInit() {
    // here making another service call to load some app data, this service calls is not related to our problem/requirement 
}


gotoApp1() {
        this._service.getApp1Key().subscribe(key => {
          const myform = document.getElementById('app1') as HTMLFormElement;
          myform.action = key.app1Link;
          this.keyField = key.accessKey;
          this.timeOutField = this.timeoutInterval.toString(); // time out in seconds
          myform.submit();
        });
    }



gotoApp2() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

1. When i do click on "App-1" anchor tag/link it just refreshes page
   first time and if i clicked again or second time it is opening the new app
   in new tab.
2. I think angular takes time to load value of "input" tag or happens somethings wrong.

Any body have faced this situation and how to fix this?

Note: So requirement is here, new tab should be open when i click first time on link "App-1". Also no any logs found on console.

Comment: What is it are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to pass data via form submission and then navigate to a specific URL?

Comment: @Joshua, calling function on anchor tag click event, which is passing data to input HTML control from code/function i.e. submission of form though code and then navigating to URL.

Comment: I'm not sure if form.submit will trigger a page reload but you can do event.preventDefault() and return false for the click handler to stop page from navigating and do it manually via router.navigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort i found solution to open new tab on submitting html form from function which is called on anchor tag click event,

HTML code:

```
<div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <div>
      <form #app1 id="app1" method="post" stype.display="none" target="_blank" [action]="appLink">
        <input #key id="key" name="key" type="hidden">
        <input #timeOut id="timeOut" name='timeOut' type="hidden">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <nav>
          <a class="item selected" href="#"><img class="icon" src="images/work.svg"><span>Container</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item" style="cursor: pointer" (click)="gotoApp1()"><img class="icon" src="images/app1.svg"><span>App-1</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item" style="cursor: pointer" (click)="gotoApp2()"><img class="icon" src="images/app2.svg"><span>App-2</span></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts code:

```
export class MajorComponent implements OnInit {

private appLink:string;
private timeoutInterval = 2000; // seconds
@ViewChild('app1') app1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('key') key: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('timeOut') timeOut: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    // here making another service call to load some app data, this service calls is not related to our problem/requirement 
}


gotoApp1() {

        this._service.getApp1Key().subscribe(key => {
          const myform = this.app1.nativeElement;
          const keyField = this.key.nativeElement;
          keyField.value = key.accessKey;
          const timeOutField = this.timeOut.nativeElement;
          timeOutField.value = this.timeoutInterval.toString(); // time out in seconds
          myform.submit();
        });
    }



gotoApp2() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

i think problem is with href attribute, here i am opening new tab on form submission through a function, so removed the href attribute and in typescript code use ElementRef from angular/core instead using document.getElementById() method of DOM, to set the values which is required on form submission, so not required to bind it on HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your anchor tag to

```
<button class="nav-item" type="button" (click)="gotoApp1()"><img class="icon" src="images/app1.svg"><span>App-1</span></button>
```

Most probably you see sharp (#) at the end of your url.

It is not proper to use anchor if you do not use href attribute. You are waiting a button behaviour from an anchor. But there are hacky ways.

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

or `(click)="gotoApp1($event)"` and inside the function

```
    gotoApp1(event) {
      event.preventdefault();
      ... 
    }
```

Comment: but in a code every where we used anchor tag and wanted to use with anchor tag to make consistent code. So how to keep anchor tag behavior as same like button, because with button its working.